# Creating a custom view, best approach

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

How should I create this custom View? The actual slider doesnt need to slide, it is set once programatically and then just stays in that position. I was thinking that even if I extended ProgressBar I would still need to do some maths in order for the arrow to appear directly over a notch, so maybe drawing each Rect onto a canvas and then the thumb above in the correct place would be a better approach? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Does the arrow can be placed between the rectangles?

Comment: no,just directly over a bar

Comment: If I understand right only 19 positions?

Comment: One shortcut I see, if you know what the background color is going to be, is to draw a wide Rectangle ShapeDrawable whose Paint's Shader is a gradient from Red to Green. Then draw black (or bg color) rectangles all the way across to divide them up, by just drawing the same one over and over with increasing offset. This saves you from creating 19 unique shape drawables or paints.

Comment: 19 positions yes. ahh i see what you mean TenFour04. How can I get the thumb in there with it? would the ShapeDrawable and an ImageView be inside a custom View (extending RelativeLayout or such)? I will need the thumb to align up perfectly with the thumbs

Comment: and make 19 triangles and play with the visibility